# Make iframe like a input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to recreated this plugin - http://xing.github.io/wysihtml5/

I want learn how they did it, but the code is a mess, so i'm writing my own.

This is what i already made - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjQprM

As you can see, i was able to initialize the plugin just with a data-editor="init", and create and append an iframe inside.. but.. how make this writable, like an input?

I'm breaking my brain thinking how to do that.

ANY help is very welcome!

Thanks

Code:

```
var Editor = Editor || {};

(function(Editor) {

  var Editor = function(editor) {
    this.editor = editor;
    this.editorWidth = editor.width() || '100%';
    this.editorHeight = editor.height() || '100px';

    this.init();
  };

  Editor.prototype.init = function() {
    this.basicStyles();
    this.createEditor();
  };

  Editor.prototype.basicStyles = function() {
    this.editor
      .css('border-width', '1px')
      .css('border-style', 'solid')
      .css('border-color', 'grey');

    this.editor
      .css('padding-top', '10px')
      .css('padding-right', '10px')
      .css('padding-bottom', '10px')
      .css('padding-right', '10px');
  };

  Editor.prototype.createEditor = function() {
    if (this.createIframe()) {
      this.createNecessaryTagsInsideHead();
      this.createNecessaryTagsInsideBody();
    }
  };

  Editor.prototype.createIframe = function() {
    this.iframe = $('<iframe>', {
      'data-editor': 'iframe',
      'frameborder': 0,
      'scrolling': 'no',
      'width': this.editorWidth,
      'height': this.editorHeight,
      'border': '1px solid red',
      'background': 'red'
    }).appendTo(this.editor);

    this.headInsideIframe = $(this.iframe.find('head'));
    this.bodyInsideIframe = $(this.iframe.find('body'));

    if (this.iframe) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false; 
    }
  };

  Editor.prototype.createNecessaryTagsInsideHead = function() {
    this.headInsideIframe.append('<meta charset="UTF-8" />');

  };

  Editor.prototype.createNecessaryTagsInsideBody = function() {

  };



  window.onload = function() {
    var el = $('[data-editor]');

    var editor = new Editor(el);
  };

}(Editor));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an editable DOM element, set the `contenteditable` attribute of the element to `true`.

So in your code, change

```
<div data-editor="init"></div>
```

to

```
<div data-editor="init" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Then the user can edit the contents of the div!

Comment: I NEED SAY.. I did not expect something as simple and silly as that!

Comment: and it works in IE8+?? :OOOOOO.. lol.. i can't believe.. this is the best day of my programmer life!!!!!!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH @Maximillian

Comment: When I discovered this originally it blew my mind. Amazing how obscure some of the HTML5 stuff can be despite the obvious usefulness.